# How do you set the SWP flag for iscsi on linux?

Tags: linux, iscsi

I want to export an iSCSI share read-only; I understand that's done with SWP, but... I can't figure out how to set that on a LUN.  I've tried via config file and via command line...
Example:

```
<target netstore>
  <backing-store /dev/sda3>
    SWP on
  </backing store>
</target>
```

Linux 5.4.0.65(mint)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to use the [iscsi-swp](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/iscsi-swp.1.html) command.

Comment: Thank you!
For those who need it, it's part of the **libiscsi-bin** package.

Comment: Ack... but it doesn't seem to work; when I do `iscsi-swp iscsi://localhost/netstore/1 -swp on`, it just prints the SWP.  Is there a way to _set_ it for Linux targets?

Comment: @Thor make sure you use two dashes for the —swp parameter, or single dash -s. If it’s still misbehaving, try setting the debug level to a value like 10 or 5 (not sure what these are, but generally the higher the value the more verbose the debug output). With the debug turned on, you should see step-by-step what’s being done by the command, and if there’s a failure somewhere along the way, you’ll see what it is, hopefully.

Comment: Ahh... thanks!  the `--swp on` did the trick

Comment: I’m glad that helped!